# Write environmental variable on client machines, based on AD information

Tags: active-directory, environment-variables

I want to alter the `logon.bat` script for our AD users (Windows XP/vista/7 machines and a few servers), so that it writes an environmental variable upon login based on some AD information, like "what group is the user in".

Basically: `SET MyADGroup=<some magic query/command that can get that AD information here>`

Some Google searches got me into dsget and so on, but that was only on servers and not built into any "normal client".

Comment: This seems silly for any number of reasons - including the fact that a user might be in more than one group. Can you tell us what problem you're actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

I would think it would be easier to use GPP:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Group-Policy-Preferences-Get-Them-Running-Today.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the groups a user belongs to using the "NET USER" command:

```
net user <username> /domain
```

The command provides lots of informations, including group membership; but storing that in a variable can get tricky, because you would need to parse the command's output.